# Why it cannot resolve a refence to main database object in this Database-Project?

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, database-project

I have a database project where there is a stored-procedure spBarFoo.

Whan I try to deploy the project, even though I refer to a table within the data base I work on I receive warnings like:

Warning xx  SQL04151: Procedure: [dbo].[spBarFoo] *has an unresolved reference to object* **[Foo].[dbo].[Bar].**    D:...\Schema Objects\Schemas\dbo\Programmability\Stored Procedures\spBarFoo.proc.sql

Warning xx  SQL04151: Procedure: [dbo].[spBarFoo] has an unresolved reference to object **[Foo].[dbo].[Bar].[Id]**  D:...\Schema Objects\Schemas\dbo\Programmability\Stored Procedures\spBarFoo.proc.sql

Warning xx  SQL04151: Procedure: [dbo].[spBarFoo] has an unresolved reference to object **[Foo].[dbo].[Bar].[Name]**    D:...\Schema Objects\Schemas\dbo\Programmability\Stored Procedures\spBarFoo.proc.sql

Warning xx  SQL04151: Procedure: [dbo].[spBarFoo] has an unresolved reference to object **[Foo].[dbo].[Bar].[Surname]** D:...\Schema Objects\Schemas\dbo\Programmability\Stored Procedures\spBarFoo.proc.sql

Here is the citation from the stored-proc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [spBarFoo] @birthDate datetimeoffset
AS

-- Some stuff

INSERT INTO Foo..[Bar](
           [Id]
          ,[Name]
          ,[Surname]

-- Rest of the sp
```

**Question**:
How can I make Visual Studio to resolve this reference to the Foo..[Bar] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove explicit database name from procedure. I.e. instead of `INSERT INTO Foo..[Bar](` just use `INSERT INTO [Bar](`.